# Should there be "seams" at the edge of the "tiles" when I fill using an image as a pattern in Gimp?

Tags: gimp, patterns

I want to visualize what an image(768x1024) looks like when it's scaled down and tiled. I use `Gimp`, so I *select*, ctrl-*scale* to something small (whateverx180), *select*, *copy*, *edit/paste as../new pattern* (give a name, *save*), then I open a blank white canvas, and *fill* with the pattern:

[image]

Is it the expected behavior of the tool that I see those **seams** (the background color filters through) on the edge of the individual pattern?<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub>1. It doesn't happen with the default patterns supplied. And I can fill the canvas with blue first to avoid it. The *affected area* parameters don't change the result. I made a comparison using Imagemagick's [*montage*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159266), and it tiles without those seams. I am a beginner.</sub>

Comment: The fill tool doesn't add the seams, they are on your scaled image (try to see the borders with a color picker) and probably are a consequence of the scaling operation. How is the border of the original image?

Comment: I don't know much about the Gimp, but that *is* the expected behaviour if your selection tool is anti-aliased. There's normally a checkbox to turn that off.

Comment: Thank you for your advice both! @PaoloGibellini Indeed I was focused on the fill and didn't pay attention to the scaling tool - it has an "interpolation" item, containing none, linear, cubic and sinc - it seems selecting _none_ removes those seams. On the other hand I could reproduce this with any dark image from the web; and selecting transparent bg shows lines with varying gray gradients i.e. checkermarks. But scaling indeed. If you make an answer I'll select it. Thanks again.

Comment: @StanRogers Thank you, I see you were also [spot on](http://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/gimp-tools-transform.html#gimp-tool-transform) as those settings are about anti-aliasing as you suggested...

Comment: @Amphiteót You are welcome, I've posted a more formal answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fill tool doesn't add seams, it simply repeats the pattern putting it as adjacent tiles.
The problem could be into the way you have resized your original image.

When you [scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling) a bitmap image, you create a *new* image with a different number of points, and the information used for the values of the pixels of the new image is obtained using an *algorithm* (in GIMP you can [choose](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-scale.html) between several formulas).

Depending on the method used, you can obtain different results. Sometimes the operations introduces artefacts (in your case it seems a [Moiré pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern)).

You can *change* the scaling method or *correct* directly the resized image.